# How to pass ActivityId (GUID) to aspx page

Tags: c#, guid, nlog, global-asax

In Global.asax I have added this method so I can get GUID for every request

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

And I can get this GUID written to my NLog file.

How can I pass this to my custom aspx page (error page) so user can send my this GUID for me to look in error file easily?

In asax.cs file I tried to add inside **Page_Load** this

```
string _SessionGuid = Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId.ToString();
```

but VS says this error although I have **System.Diagnostics** reference:

> Error 21  'System.Web.TraceContext' does not contain a definition for
>   'CorrelationManager' and no extension method 'CorrelationManager'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.TraceContext' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:...\ErrorPage.aspx.cs

Comment: `Trace` is a [similar named property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the `Page` class. You have to fully-qualified call "your" `Trace` like `System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by my own.

In HomeController I have

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly string _SessionGuid = 
        Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId.ToString();
....
}
```

And in ActionResult this

```
public ActionResult About()
{
   Session["test"] = _SessionGuid;
   ....
}
```

When error happens, I route it to ErrorController with this code inside

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var errGUID = (string)Session["test"];
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errGUID;

        return View();
    }
}
```